How to turn off Ubuntu's "windows stick together" feature when pressing super+left-arrow and super+right-arrow?
I'm used to GNOME on Fedora where I can push Super+arrow-key to make the active window automatically scale to take up half the desktop. However on Ubuntu there is an extra dialog that shows other applications. I'm not sure exactly how this dialog is meant to work but no matter what I do another application is assigned to stick to the current window. When alt-tabbing the pair of "stuck" applications come up together forcing everything else into the background.
I've tried installing gnome-session and switching to that at log in but the behavior remains.
How can I disable this feature?

This behavior is caused by the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant extension for GNOME. Using either the Extensions app or Extension Manager toggle Ubuntu Tiling Assistant off to stop it. Or edit the extension settings to disable the Tiling Popup and "Raise together" options.

Ubuntu added a Gnome extension called Ubuntu Tiling Assistant, which changed the default tiling behavior to work more like tiling on Windows.
Personally, I find this annoying, so I disabled it on Ubuntu 24.04 / Gnome 46.
You can disable the popup and the "raise together" behavior by running these terminal commands:
# disable tiling popup
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.tiling-assistant enable-tiling-popup false

# disable raise together
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.tiling-assistant enable-raise-tile-group false

It can also be disabled by opening the Extensions GUI in settings. Go to the settings for Ubuntu Tiling Assistant, and flip the relevant toggles.


